# Ignoring multiple header lines in a CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I've worked a bit with Ruby's CSV module, but am having some problems getting it to ignore multiple header lines.

Specifically, here are the first twenty lines of a file I want to parse:

```
USGS Digital Spectral Library splib06a
Clark and others 2007, USGS, Data Series 231.

For further information on spectrsocopy, see: http://speclab.cr.usgs.gov

ASCII Spectral Data file contents:
line 15 title
line 16 history
line 17 to end:  3-columns of data:
     wavelength    reflectance    standard deviation

(standard deviation of 0.000000 means not measured)
(      -1.23e34  indicates a deleted number)
----------------------------------------------------
Olivine GDS70.a Fo89 165um   W1R1Bb AREF
copy of splib05a r 5038
       0.205100      -1.23e34        0.090781
       0.213100      -1.23e34        0.018820
       0.221100      -1.23e34        0.005416
       0.229100      -1.23e34        0.002928
```

The actual headers are given on the tenth line, and the seventeenth line is where the actual data start.

Here's my code:

```
require "nyaplot"

# Note that DataFrame basically just inherits from Ruby's CSV module.
class SpectraHelper < Nyaplot::DataFrame
  class << self
    def from_csv filename
      df = super(filename, col_sep: ' ') do |csv|
        csv.convert do |field, info|
          STDERR.puts "Field is #{field}"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def csv_headers
    [:wavelength, :reflectance, :standard_deviation]
  end
end


def read_asc filename
  f = File.open(filename, "r")
  16.times do
    line = f.gets
    puts "Ignoring #{line}"
  end

  d = SpectraHelper.from_csv(f)
end
```

The output suggests that my calls to `f.gets` are not actually ignoring those lines, and I can't understand why. Here are the first few lines of output:

```
Field is Clark
Field is and
Field is others
Field is 2007,
Field is USGS,
```

I tried looking for a tutorial or example which shows processing of more complicated CSV files, but haven't had much luck. If someone could point me towards a resource which answers this question, I would be grateful (and would prefer to mark that as accepted over a solution to my specific problem — but both would be appreciated).

Using Ruby 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem here was not with my understanding of CSV, but rather with now `Nyaplot::DataFrame` handles CSV files.

Basically, Nyaplot doesn't actually store things as CSVs. CSV is just an intermediate format. So a simple way to handle the files makes use of @khelli's suggestion:

```
def read_asc filename
  Nyaplot::DataFrame.new(CSV.open(filename, 'r',
     col_sep: ' ',
     headers: [:wavelength, :reflectance, :standard_deviation],
     converters: :numeric).
   drop(16).
   map do |csv_row|
    csv_row.to_h.delete_if { |k,v| k.nil? }
  end)
end
```

Thanks, everyone, for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It believe that you are using `::open` which uses `IO.open`. This method will open the file again.

I modified the script a bit

```
require 'csv'

class SpectraHelper < CSV
  def self.from_csv(filename)
    df = open(filename, 'r' , col_sep: ' ') do |csv|
      csv.drop(16).each {|c| p c}
    end
  end
end

def read_asc(filename)
  SpectraHelper.from_csv(filename)
end

read_asc "data/csv1.csv"
```

Comment: Where did you find the `drop` method? I don't see it in the docs.

Comment: @mohawkjohn A file opened this way is an IO-object, which includes the Enumerable module.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use the CSV module since your file is not well formatted. the following code will read the file and give you an array of your records:

```
  lines = File.open(filename,'r').readlines
  lines.slice!(0,16)
  records = lines.map {|line| line.chomp.split}
```

the `records`output:

```
[["0.205100", "-1.23e34", "0.090781"], ["0.213100", "-1.23e34", "0.018820"], ["0.221100", "-1.23e34", "0.005416"], ["0.229100", "-1.23e34", "0.002928"]]
```

Comment: This is not actually an answer to the question I asked.